# What's the difference between using a variable or %s in Python string formatting?

Tags: python, python-2.7

What is the difference between defining a variable and using it in a string and putting %s in a string and passing in the value after?

```
site = "Stackoverflow"
site + " is great!"

"%s is great!" % "Stackoverflow"
```

Printing either of these gives the same result so when is it better to use one over the other?

Comment: Placeholder strings, mainly. When you have multiple strings to insert, it's easier to specify formatting than concatenate them.

Comment: Format strings give you more control over the formatting, e.g. width, leading characters, justification, etc. For straight `str` concatenation its a bit of a wash, use whatever is most readable. As soon as you have mixed types, format strings are usually more understandable. Note: I personally prefer `str.format()` over old style `%` formats.

Comment: Using straight concatenation result in the creation of a new string for each concat performed. So for 2 strings its no big deal, as the `%` or `str.format` also create a new string. However if you concatenate several strings together e.g. `"stack " + "overflow" + "is" + "great"`, you have created 2 more temporary strings during the concatenation process, which are thrown away straight away. So it is more efficient to use `%` as it amortizes the number of newly created strings at 1.

Comment: @PaulRooney There's no amortization involved; only one `str` object is created, period.

Comment: @chepner so it the case that python is able to do what java does i.e. switch out a series of concatenations for some sort of stringbuilder or join like operation?

Comment: No, you're just misusing the term "amortization". `s1  + s2 + s3` indeed has to create a temporary `str` object for `s1 + s2` before creating the final result concatenating the temp object and `s3`, while `'%s %s %s' % (s1, s2, s3)` creates only one `str` object consisting of the three original objects.

Comment: Amortization applies to a sequence of operations like appending to a `list`. Any one `append` might required resizing the list, but such resizing is guaranteed not to happen for *every* operation in a series of appends. In that case, you can say the amortized cost of an arbitrary `append` is less than the possible worst-case cost.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep certain string constants in the same file, or on the top most of the file, you can declare the string with the placeholders as constants, then replace the placeholders with actual variable at run time through the % syntax.

This also allows greater re-usability.
Eg. you can store a single constant `"%s is %s years old"`.

Using this syntax might also make the string more readable.

Answer (score -1):

For two strings, there is little difference.

For multiple strings, s1 + s2 + s3 is less efficient, as it has to create a temporary str object for the first concatenation, where as both "%s %s %s" % (s1, s2, s3) and "{} {} {}".format(s1, s2, s3) creates the final str object immediately.

```
One:

'string' + 'string'


Two:

'%s %s' % ('one', 'two')
'{} {}'.format('one', 'two')
```

There is a great article on this here: https://pyformat.info/

Also the docs are a great resource: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

Version one is less efficient with larger amounts of concatenation.

Comment: For two strings, there is little difference. For *multiple* strings, `s1 + s2 + s3` is less efficient, as it has to create a temporary `str` object for the first concatenation, where as both `"%s %s %s" % (s1, s2, s3)` and `"{} {} {}".format(s1, s2, s3)`  creates the final `str` object immediately.

Comment: @chepner Please feel free to contribute to the answer